# Ruby comparing strings

Tags: ruby, string

I'm trying to compare `message[0]` with `"CONNECT"` but it just fails:

```
puts message[0].dump 
->"\x00C\x00O\x00N\x00N\x00E\x00C\x00T\x00"
puts "CONNECT".dump
->"CONNECT"
```

Can somebody explain me why?

Comment: What’s the result of `message[0].encoding`?

Comment: This looks like a UTF-16 encoding. Your input stream, where you're getting `message`, probably needs to have a character-set encoding defined. See the `mode` documentation for [`IO.new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-new) for a starting point and check their examples for setting encodings.

Comment: message[0] is ASCII-8BIT encoding   Is this why i get all these null characters?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a lot of NULL characters in your string. It would be best to figure out where they are coming from, but to just remove them you can use this.

```
 def remove_null_chrs(str) 
     str.unpack('C*').select{|x|x != 0}.pack('C*')
 end
```

For instance

```
remove_null_chrs("\x00C\x00O\x00N\x00N\x00E\x00C\x00T\x00")
=> "CONNECT"
```

Comment: It could actually be that your input is UTF-16, but then it would be truncated since that last \x00 should be followed by another character then. But to illustrate : `"\x00C\x00O\x00N\x00N\x00E\x00C\x00T".force_encoding('UTF-16BE').encode('UTF-8') # => "CONNECT"`

Comment: You should edit your answer instead of posting a comment on it if you want to add to it.

Answer (score 0):

message[0] is in different encoding

Try this `message[0].encode("UTF-8", :invalid=>:replace, :replace=>"?")`

If it does not work you have to try different encodings. I think this answer is valid only for 1.9.* version. For older versions I think you have to require iconv

Comment: Maybe this acually as nothing to do with your question. It might be only a strange character between each letter

Comment: thanks, I change the encoding but it still ain't working it appears that message[0][0] is "\x00" and message[0][1] is "C"